# web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.coinbase), 'ether').toNumber() gives error

Tags: truffle, ganache

*web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.coinbase), 'ether').toNumber()*

gives this error:

```
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:369506
>     throw new Error('Provided address "'+ address +'" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address
> which can\'t be converted.');
>     ^
> 
> Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization
> checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be
> converted.
>     at Method.inputAddressFormatter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-helpers/src/formatters.js:409:1)
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:144:1
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at Method.formatInput (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:142:1)
>     at Method.toPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:177:1)
>     at Eth.send [as getBalance] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:467:1)
>     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:29
>     at Script.runInContext (vm.js:134:20)
>     at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/console.js:199:1)
>     at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/console.js:213:1)
>     at ReplManager.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/repl.js:118:1)
>     at bound (domain.js:395:14)
>     at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:408:12)
>     at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:639:10)
>     at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:13)
>     at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
>     at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)
>     at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:654:8)
>     at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:933:14)
>     at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:712:7)
>     at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:184:10)
>     at ReadStream.emit (events.js:188:13)
```

truffle version:

```
Truffle v5.0.1 (core: 5.0.1)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v11.6.0
```

I'm trying to set up a test environment, ganache-cli (Ganache CLI v6.2.5 (ganache-core: 2.3.3)) is running in another terminal window.

Comment: What does `web3.eth.coinbase` returns? From the message it seems to returns `undefined` which is an invalid address

Comment: yes, it returns `undefiined`
it seems like 'eth' doesn't have membe 'coinbase', because pressing TAB is not finishing the sentence
`web3.eth.accounts` exists, but `web3.eth.accounts[0]` returns undefined as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this script with your exact same versions and it works `truffle exec balance.js`

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const coinbase = await web3.eth.getCoinbase();
  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase);
  console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
  console.log("------------------");
  console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(await web3.eth.getCoinbase()), "ether"));
}
```

Comment: yes! It works. Thank you really much for your help!
`Using network 'development'.

100
------------------
100
`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because you arent calling coinbase properly. It eth.getbalance function requires an address type.

Change this to:

```
web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.getCoinbase()), 'ether').toNumber()
```

Comment: it's still not working, I get the same error
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:369506
    throw new Error('Provided address "'+ address +'" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can\'t be converted.');
`

Comment: Try it without the promise i.e `web3.eth.getCoinbase`

Comment: that works and `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` also works. it gives an address: `'0x1c48f9c54db0c9c27a28b9f78d528b31abba978f'`

Comment: If it works accept the answer .. what changes did you make?

Comment: Curious I as you said it still wasn’t working

Comment: no, i mean `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` works, but `web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.getCoinbase()).toNumber())` still doesn't work.
`web3.utils.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.getCoinbase).toNumber())` is also not working.

Comment: @imestin With truffle v5 you are using web3 v1 so functions return promises to use them you need to await for their result. Like this `web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(await web3.eth.getCoinbase()), 'ether')`, also `.fromWei` returns a string and you cannot call `.toNumber()`. Look at the documentation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html for the return types.

Comment: `evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(await web3.eth.getCoinbase()), 'ether')
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
` it's still not working

Comment: I would be following this guide (https://medium.com/coinmonks/blockchain-development-environment-775176fd88f3) to set up a test environment. I already changed `web3.fromWei` to `web3.utils.fromWei`, because I have newer version of Truffle. I downgraded node by this command `sudo npm install -g n # install node version manager "n"
sudo n stable # install the latest stable version of node` because I had problems with npm install. It is possible that I still have some problem with npm though, but I don't know how to test it.